# How can write a query form calculate two select query Minus?

Tags: sql-server

I'm new in `sql server`,write two query,first select query this:

```
select [Cycle],count([Price]) as countbehi 
from [ClubEatc].[dbo].[CycleAnalysisTable]
where cast([Price] as float)<cast('0' as float) and 
      (cast([Telno] as bigint)>=04137626838 and cast([Telno] as bigint)<=04137629000)
group by [Cycle]
```

show me this result:

```
    Cycle          countbehi 
941     -942        841
942     -943        968
943     -944        1238
944     -945        785
945     -946        1369
951     -952        1223
```

and second query this:

```
select [Cycle],count([Price]) as countbehi 
from [ClubEatc].[dbo].[CycleAnalysisTable]
where cast([Price] as float)>cast('0' as float) and 
      (cast([Telno] as bigint)>=04137626838 and cast([Telno] as bigint)<=04137629000)
group by [Cycle]
```

and that show me this:

```
    Cylce          countbehi 
941     -942        962
942     -943        821
943     -944        848
944     -945        1014
945     -946        732
951     -952        880
```

i want write query show me with this step:

```
-run select query#1
-run select query#2
-if (query#1 countbehi-query#2 countbehi)>0 then show me in result.
```

if want explain with up really example:

```
in query#1 countbehi=841 and in query#2 countbehi=962-->minus=-121 then not show in result.
in query#1 countbehi=968 and in query#2 countbehi=821-->minus=147 then show in result.
and...
```

how can i write query for that purpose,thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this script:**

```
SELECT Query1.* FROM(
    select [Cycle],count([Price]) as countbehi 
    from [ClubEatc].[dbo].[CycleAnalysisTable]
    where cast([Price] as float)<cast('0' as float) and 
          (cast([Telno] as bigint)>=04137626838 and cast([Telno] as bigint)<=04137629000)
    group by [Cycle]
)Query1
INNER JOIN (
    select [Cycle],count([Price]) as countbehi 
    from [ClubEatc].[dbo].[CycleAnalysisTable]
    where cast([Price] as float)>cast('0' as float) and 
          (cast([Telno] as bigint)>=04137626838 and cast([Telno] as bigint)<=04137629000)
    group by [Cycle]
)Query2 ON Query1.[Cycle]=Query2.[Cycle] 
WHERE (Query1.countbehi - Query2.countbehi) > 0
```